# How to put elements of a list of vectors of different lengths into a data frame, with elements of vectors being separated as different columns

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector, element

I would like to put elements of my list into a data frame. The list has this shape :

```
$`1`
    SW        GHS         GS 
0.49075730 0.46511628 0.02564103 

...

$`95`
   GHS         SW        LLB         GS 
 0.06896552 0.03448276 0.03448276 0.00000000 

$`96`
   GHS         SW         TD 
0.40736411 0.42843691 0.09003831
```

As you can see, the elements of the vectors are not always in the same order, and their number is variable as well. 
I would like it to be put in a data frame like this :

```
     GHS         SW         TD         GS        LLB
1 0.46511628 0.49075730         NA 0.02564103         NA
2 0.06896552 0.03448276         NA 0.00000000 0.03448276
3 0.40736411 0.42843691 0.09003831         NA         NA
```

I hope you can help me, I have looked for similar question but so far was only able to find cases in which the amount and orders of elements in the vectors were consistent ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution below (1) converts each list element into a dataframe where `t()` is used to get the element names to be column names in the dataframe, and (2) row-binds those dataframes together where data.table's `fill` argument is helpful for the inconsistent vector lengths/names.

```
mylist <- list(
    one = c(SW=0.49, GHS=0.46, GS=0.03),
    two = c(GHS=0.07, GW = 0.03, LLW=0.03, GS=0.00),
    six = c(GHS=0.41, SW=0.42, TD=0.09)
)

temp <- lapply(mylist, function(x) data.frame(t(x)))
data.table::rbindlist(temp, fill=TRUE)
```

output:

```
     SW  GHS   GS   GW  LLW   TD
1: 0.49 0.46 0.03   NA   NA   NA
2:   NA 0.07 0.00 0.03 0.03   NA
3: 0.42 0.41   NA   NA   NA 0.09
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this and for the explainations, I am only beginning on R so your answer is more than helpful =)

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `purrr::full_join` within `purrr::reduce`

```
# Reproducible sample data
set.seed(2018)
lst <- list(
    `1` = setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(runif(3), ncol = 3)), c("SW", "GHS", "GS")),
    `95` = setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(runif(4), ncol = 4)), c("GHS", "SW", "LLB", "GS")),
    `96` = setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(runif(3), ncol = 3)), c("GHS", "SW", "TD")))

# Merge
library(purrr)
reduce(lst, full_join)
#         SW       GHS         GS       LLB        TD
#1 0.3361535 0.4637233 0.06058539        NA        NA
#2 0.4743142 0.1974336 0.60675886 0.3010486        NA
#3 0.9586547 0.1300121         NA        NA 0.5468495
```